# SQL - Get Min Date for every PlayerID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I tried to solve a question from my **homework**, where they ask me to create a new table and add a few new columns to it (based off calculations from joined tabled).

I am asked to find the first date in which the player made a purchase after the 1st of January 2021, and the last date in which he has made another purchase (also after January 1st, 2021).

I tried to do the following:

```
select p.PlayerID, p.InstallDate, p.Platform, p.[Country ], p.LoginType, sum(ddn.Revenue + p.LifeTimeRevenue) as LTRevenueNew, min(ddn.[Date ]), max(ddn.[Date ])
    --into dbo.PlayersNew
from dbo.Players p
    inner join dbo.DailyDataNew ddn
    on p.PlayerID = ddn.PlayerID
    group by p.PlayerID, p.InstallDate, p.Platform, p.[Country ], p.LoginType, ddn.[Date ]
    having convert(date, ddn.[Date ]) > '2020-11-26'
```

however I'm getting the same dates for all rows, instead of getting the relative (and correct) dates of each playerID.

```
PlayerID    InstallDate Platform    Country     LoginType   LTRevenueNew    (No column name)    (No column name)
836 4/2/2015    Android US  Facebook    14382   2020-11-27 00:00:00.000 2020-11-27 00:00:00.000
836 4/2/2015    Android US  Facebook    14382   2020-11-28 00:00:00.000 2020-11-28 00:00:00.000
836 4/2/2015    Android US  Facebook    14382   2020-11-29 00:00:00.000 2020-11-29 00:00:00.000
836 4/2/2015    Android US  Facebook    14382   2020-11-30 00:00:00.000 2020-11-30 00:00:00.000
836 4/2/2015    Android US  Facebook    14382   2020-12-12 00:00:00.000 2020-12-12 00:00:00.000
836 4/2/2015    Android US  Facebook    14382   2020-12-13 00:00:00.000 2020-12-13 00:00:00.000
```

> Thoughts?

Comment: Grouping and aggregating on the same column is never the right choice. The columns in your `GROUP BY` are the columns you *don't* want to aggregate. You have `ddn.[Date ]` in both the `GROUP BY` and aggregate functions.

Comment: `convert(date, ddn.[Date ])` WHY are you doing this? Never convert when you don't need to. And make every effort to avoid converting (explicitly or implicitly) when filtering as this can lead to serious inefficiencies. And why did you choose to give your column a name that is both meaningless and violating regular identifiers rules (that space in the name)? Learn good habits.

Comment: Please post your tables structure, some test data and desired result [mre]

Answer (score 0):

This may not help depending on what version of SQL the school youre at has set up for you (I assume in a vm, with a dev license). If this doesnt work you have other options like using correlated subqueries (ew gross) to do the same thing. Ill be typing that up for you in the mean time. I also put some notes in here, just generic stuff.

Please keep in mind this isnt tested, but what youre after is pretty easy to get at. Hope it helps!

```
--Proper indentation is your friend
--Doesnt matter hwo you do it as long as youre consistent
-- most people use sql formatters and leave it at that
-- tyr notepad++'s free "Poor man's sql formatter", its great
SELECT -- youll notice all my key words are capitalized
       -- this isnt necessary but it helps readability a little bit
    p.PlayerID
    , p.InstallDate
    , p.Platform
    , p.[Country ]  -- spaces in objects names are a no-no
    , p.LoginType
    , SUM(ddn.Revenue + p.LifeTimeRevenue) as LTRevenueNew  
                        -- unless working with char restrictions 
                        -- due to quirky applications, 
                        -- try to abbreviate only when necessary
    , MIN(ddn.[Date ]) OVER 
        (
            PARTITION BY p.PlayerID
            ORDER BY ddn.[Date ]
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        )       
    , MAX(ddn.[Date ]) OVER 
        (
            PARTITION BY p.PlayerID
            ORDER BY ddn.[Date ] DESC
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        )
--INTO dbo.PlayersNew
FROM 
    dbo.Players p
    INNER JOIN dbo.DailyDataNew ddn
        ON p.PlayerID = ddn.PlayerID
WHERE
    ddn.[Date ])>= '2021-01-01'  -- date is a reserved word. 
                                -- do not name your objects 
                                -- the same as reserved words
GROUP BY 
    p.PlayerID
    , p.InstallDate
    , p.Platform
    , p.[Country ]
    , p.LoginType
```

Here is the correlated subquery version. Note that this isnt ideal, as the selects run for each row. Ill also provide a third answer for you here in a minute which might be less awful

```
SELECT 
    p.PlayerID
    , p.InstallDate
    , p.Platform
    , p.[Country ]
    , p.LoginType
    , SUM(ddn.Revenue + p.LifeTimeRevenue) as LTRevenueNew  
    ,  
        (
            SELECT MIN(ddn.[Date ] 
            FROM dbo.PlayersNew pn
            WHERE pn.PlayerID = p.PlayerID
        ) AS MinDate    
        -- this is a correlated subquery
        -- a subquery is considered to be correlated
        -- when it refers to an outer object
        -- this is that reference "pn.PlayerID = p.PlayerID"
    ,  
        (
            SELECT MAX(ddn.[Date ] 
            FROM dbo.PlayersNew pn
            WHERE pn.PlayerID=p.PlayerID
        ) AS MaxDate    
--INTO dbo.PlayersNew
FROM 
    dbo.Players p
    INNER JOIN dbo.DailyDataNew ddn
        ON p.PlayerID = ddn.PlayerID
WHERE
    ddn.[Date ])>= '2021-01-01'
GROUP BY 
    p.PlayerID
    , p.InstallDate
    , p.Platform
    , p.[Country ]
    , p.LoginType
```

here is yet another way to solve the issue.

```
SELECT 
    p.PlayerID
    , p.InstallDate
    , p.Platform
    , p.[Country ]
    , p.LoginType
    , SUM(ddn.Revenue + p.LifeTimeRevenue) as LTRevenueNew  
    , mmd.MinDate   
    , mmd.MaxDate   
--INTO dbo.PlayersNew
FROM 
    dbo.Players p
    INNER JOIN dbo.DailyDataNew ddn
        ON p.PlayerID = ddn.PlayerID
    INNER JOIN  -- JOIN on subquery for the data
        (
            SELECT 
                dn.PlayerID
                , MIN(ddn.[Date ]) AS MinDate
                , MAX(ddn.[Date ]) AS MaxDate
            FROM 
                dbo.DailyDataNew dn 
            WHERE
                ddn.[Date ])>= '2021-01-01'
            GROUP BY dn.PlayerID
        ) mmd ON p.PlayerID =mmd.PlayerID 
            AND ddn.PlayerID = mmd.PlayerID
WHERE
    ddn.[Date ])>= '2021-01-01'
GROUP BY 
    p.PlayerID
    , p.InstallDate
    , p.Platform
    , p.[Country ]
    , p.LoginType
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading your description and what you have so far it appears you could leverage `apply()` - you can correlate your `DailyDataNew` table on `PlayerId` and do your aggregation and filtering in the apply().

```
select p.PlayerID, p.InstallDate, p.Platform, p.Country, p.LoginType, 
    ddn.Revenue + p.LifeTimeRevenue as LTRevenueNew, ddn.MinDate, ddn.MaxDate
from dbo.Players p
cross apply (
    select min(ddn.[Date]) MinDate, max(ddn.[Date]) MaxDate, sum(ddn.Revenue) Revenue
    from dbo.DailyDataNew ddn
    where ddn.PlayerID = p.PlayerID and ddn.[Date] > '20210101'
)ddn
```

I'm also assuming the space suffixes are (hopefully) a typo. Note that when specifying a literal date value it's best to use the *ISO* format YYYYMMDD date which removes ambiguity and chance it can be misinterpereted due to regional settings.

Comment: you know i was about to add apply to my list of different ways to achieve said issue, but looks like you beat me to it

Comment: Lol sorry @DougCoats you may as well copy into your answer for completeness :-)